# Is there a way to set different indexes for different contracts in couchDB with hyperledger fabric

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm using hyperledger fabric 1.4 with CouchDB 2.3.1 and 2 contracts but I'm having trouble setting the indexes in the contracts and don't get how to upload the indexes to couchDB.

These are my indexes:

META-INF/statedb/couchdb/indexes/carIndex.json

```
{
    "index": {
        "fields": [
            "idCar",
            "date"
        ]
    },
    "ddoc": "indexIdCarDoc",
    "name": "indexIdCar",
    "type": "json"
}
```

META-INF/statedb/couchdb/indexes/bikeIndex.json

```
{
    "index": {
        "fields": [
            "idBike",
            "date"
        ]
    },
    "ddoc": "indexIdBikeDoc",
    "name": "indexIdBike",
    "type": "json"
}
```

how can I tell hyperledger to set first index for mychannel_carchaincode table and the second index for the mychannel_bikechaincode table?

Also, my chaincode its written in typescript, should my META-INF/statedb/couchdb/indexes folder be in the dist folder? its that why I can't see the indexes in my couchdb after I upgrade? or indexes can only be uplodaded on instantiate?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was with the same problem. My version is 1.4.7 for hyperledger and I'm using IBM Blockchain Extesion for VS Code.
I solve when I put this folder inside lib folder in my project.

lib/META-INF/statedb/couchdb/indexes/index.json

After Upgrade the smart contract,
to make sure that works, go to the terminal and use this docker command:

`docker logs 39f4adec6057 2>&1 | grep "CouchDB index"`
where 39f4adec6057 is the peer container

if work this show something like:

[couchdb] CreateIndex -> INFO 0fc Created CouchDB index [tipoAtivo] in state database [mychannel_integra-chaincode] using design document [_design/tipoAtivoDoc]

If you are using **Typescript**, this will be compiled: make sure that this folder will be copy to dist folder. For this you can add to your package JSON a postbuild
`"postbuild": "cp -av ./META-INF dist/lib/META-INF",`

Answer (score 0):

When you give chaincode command, you have to use "use_index" parameter and have to tell the chaincode about what index it will use for this command.

Link and example:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/couchdb_tutorial.html#use-best-practices-for-queries-and-indexes

Comment: Hi, the problem is not that the chaincode doesn't use the indexes, the indexes are on all chaincodes not only in one of the contracts, how can I specify from the index.json the destination table?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem you have is. The logical separation of contracts in chaincode is implemented within the contract library itself (so it's your chaincode that conceives the separation of contracts not the peers). So it's really an artificial separation and basically you still only have a single chaincode, so all indexes you provide will be at a chaincode level and not at a contract level.
So you cannot specify indexes at the contract level, only the chaincode level.